# Syncing phpMyAdmin databases/tables automatically across two different servers

Tags: php, mysql

The Setup:

I am going to set up several websites on different servers. Then, I will create a User Registration System on websites server and export it. Then, I'll upload the same database to all the other websites servers.

So, is there a way to do something where if a person creates an account on one website, it creates an account on all the other websites? Also, the person should be able to login on any of the websites. And everything must be done automatically. I don't want to do stuff manually.

Comment: Do you have any ideas yourself? Have you made an effort to think this through? Are there designs you've rejected? This is not an application-architecting service. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: didn't understand a thing you've said.

Comment: What isn't clear? You need to show some effort to solve the problem before you ask for help. You have not shown any effort. Again, please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: so you are saying that i search the site before asking a q?

Comment: Yes. Search the site, search Google, search something. Most importantly, demonstrate some effort. Don't just dump a problem here and ask us to solve it without demonstrating that you have *tried* to figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have these alternatives:

1. you use a central authority (user account system). All systems can use that central one to authenticate a users login attempt against or whatever form of authorization is required. That certainly is the preferred approach.
2. you replicate (parts of) your database from system to system. That is possible, but less elegant and *much* more complex. Database replication and the tools required for that are well documented.
3. you use some OAuth service, either an existing, known one or you create your own service that is shared between your applications. This is a very powerful and interesting approach. But it only brings advantages if you rely on well known and wide spread services. So for example google or facebook. (Yes, these are those buttons "login with google" you see in many places)

For the central approach from alternative 1 please note that there is no reason why such a system has to be using the same type of database as your applications. In contrary, often other types are much better suited for that purpose. Take a look for example at LDAP servers.

Comment: So you are saying that I can link the 'Sign Up'/'Login' pages to one central page?

Comment: No, that is not what I wrote. There is no "central page". I wrote of a central authority, a system or server, but that is _not_ a "web server" with "pages". I wrote that your applications or application servers authenticate a user login request against the central system. That does _not_ mean they somehow forward the user, it means they do the authentication against that central system in background, so transparent for the user.

Comment: ah ok... i understand now

Answer (score 0):

instead of copying the database to all other servers, you should instead use only one database server and connect to it from your other sites.